# What are these artifacts created when deploying a GCP App?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm deploying to the GCP App Engine, I have a simple helloworld express nodejs project.  When I deploy, it's my understanding that the project is ultimately turned into a container or docker image.  I assume that's partially what I'm looking at, but when deployed there are 16 different entries added, all with different file sizes, all at the

[Entries in buckets/us.artifacts/containers/images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoDXj.png)

Is it safe to assume that the larger one is the actual apps container, and the others provide some supporting role?  If the others were deleted, would the app still run? I see new entries when re-reploying and the old ones don't seem to be deleted, my primary concern here is cloud storage filling up with tons of containers that aren't being used anymore.

Comment: A container is a collection of layers. Do not try to manage those objects and definitely do not delete one as that will break the container. The size of a layer indicates the size of the changes between layers (each layer is typically a Docker build step). https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#:~:text=When%20you%20create%20a%20new,this%20thin%20writable%20container%20layer.

Comment: Use commands to manage the container images and their artifacts (objects): https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/delete